# When did a Transformer first rely on radio to talk?

Tags: history-of, transformers

I distinctly remember a robot, or series of robots, relying on radio to talk in *[Transformers: The Movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Transformers:_The_Movie)*, which I watched on VHS as a kid.

Is that the first instance of a Transformer relying on radio to talk? I have a feeling it *wasn't* Bumblebee, even though he has recently been shown this way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the first instance of a Transformer who lacked a [voice box](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Voice_box), and was wholly reliant on using [radio](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Radio) transmissions to speak, was [Bumblebee](https://michaelbaystransformers.fandom.com/wiki/Bumblebee) in the [live-action movie from 2007](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Transformers_(film)).

In regard to the [animated movie from 1986](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/The_Transformers:_The_Movie), you may be thinking of the Junkion, [Wreck-Gar](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Wreck-Gar_(G1)), whose speech was patterned after television broadcasts, somewhat like the aliens from the 1985 movie, *[Explorers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explorers_(film))*.

However, Wreck-Gar didn't literally rely on or use radio or TV transmissions to speak. He was clearly speaking with his own voice ([Eric Idle's](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/Eric_Idle) voice) the whole time. He just mimicked the speaking style of people on TV; it was essentially a local dialect for him.

> WRECK-GAR:Have a nice day and please, close cover before striking, friends! Breep drit, aw rootie! So say the Junkions!
>
> HOT ROD: **Where'd you learn to talk like that?**
>
> WRECK-GAR: **T.V. We talk T.V. You talk some T.V.?**
>
> KUP: **I talk some T.V. And now the news, don't touch that dial.**
>
> WRECK-GAR: By George, kemo sabes, Your smashed-up friend soon like brand-new with 90-day warranty. Happy motoring! Cock-a-doodle-doo!

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you for helping me find both those.